# Cannot install openpyxl

Tags: python, pycharm, openpyxl

When I attempt to run my python code, I get this error message

```
ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'.  Use pip or conda to install openpyxl.
```

So I try to install openpvxl

```
pip install --upgrade openpyxl         
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -orch (d:\anaconda\lib\site-packages)
Requirement already satisfied: openpyxl in d:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: et-xmlfile in d:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from openpyxl) (1.1.0)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -orch (d:\anaconda\lib\site-packages)
```

This makes no difference, I still get the same error message.

I am using PyCharm and Python files.

Comment: How do you run your python code? From which environment? IDE/Terminal/something else?

Comment: From PyCharm, I am using Python files

Comment: Apparently PyCharm uses a different python environment from the one you are running pip from. You can either change the python environment  for your project in PyCharm or run pip from the environemnt that is currently selected in PyCharm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PyCharm probably sees another environment from the one that **pip** installs your libraries. You can try downloading the library from PyCharm settings:

1. File -> Settings
2. then, Project: -> Python Interpreter
3. Click a '+' sign to the right,
4. Search for the `openpyxl` library,
5. and finally, press 'Install Package'.

Comment: Did you mean to say openpyxl?

Comment: Thank you Dima and Loukas, those are excellent answers.

Comment: Check first if it's a duplicate question, which nearly everything to do with installs is.